# Oracle SQL Query COUNT

Tags: sql

Oracle SQL query:

```
TABLES
MovieInfo (mvID,title,rating,year,length,studio)
GenreInfo(mvID*,genre)
DirectInfo(mvID*,Director)
```

***Problem:*** List all genre in the database and how many movies are listed against each genre. List the genre in order of most common to least common.

Comment: Please Post code you have tried.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT genreinfo.genre,count(1) as popularity
FROM
GenreInfo , MovieInfo
WHERE MovieInfo.mvID = GenreInfo.mvID
GROUP BY genreinfo.genre
ORDER BY popularity desc;
```